# Exporting data-table to excel or word with Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable

i have a datatable with some images, I am trying to export that datatable to excel or word,with below code it does not export images, how can export datatable with images?

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.docx");
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word ";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);  
string str1 = string.Empty;      
foreach (DataColumn dtcol in dt2.Columns)
{
    Response.Write(str1 + dtcol.ColumnName);
    str1 = "\t";          
}
Response.Write("\n");
foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt2.Rows)
{
    str1 = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        Response.Write(str1 + Convert.ToString(dr1[j]));
        str1 = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");           
}
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

and here i am attaching my Datatable snap also[image]

Comment: I assume that dt2 is datatable here. Also you just want to export filePath, or want to display image in export. If you want to display image in exported file, use gridview, bind all data along with image. And try to export grid's content. You will get images.

Comment: Hello -Piyush, i am getting images in exported file with gridvew. but here i want from datatable only.

Comment: Well, directly from database, you will get filePath only. It means there is no actual image tag, just image source. If you want to get actual image, you should have image tag with image source set.

Comment: - Piyush ..could you refer any link r reference?

Comment: I mean to say that its not possible to display image directly from database. You should gridview instead, and export it to word.

Comment: ok. is there any way to change image width and height while exporting from gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have provided the sample code to export the data table to excel. also attached the image that excel looks like this after the export. 
[image]

Use following DLLs to execute the code.
1. ClosedXML.dll 
2. WindowsCore.dll 
3. DocumentFormat.OpenXML.dll 
4. PresentationCore.dll

**Code Sample:**

```
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Subject");
            dt.Columns.Add("Category");
            dt.Columns.Add("CPT");
            dt.Columns.Add("Modifier");
            dt.Columns.Add("Dx");
            dt.Columns.Add("GuideLine");
            dt.Columns.Add("Insurance");
            dt.Columns.Add("FilePath");

            string path = Server.MapPath("Image/stock-illustration-1977033-dandelion-in-the-wind.jpg");

            dt.Rows.Add("Billing Steps", "Billing", "NA", "NA", "Billing Steps is very easy", "NA", "NA", path);
            dt.Rows.Add("Billing Steps", "Billing", "NA", "NA", "Billing Steps is very easy", "NA", "NA", "");

            dt.AcceptChanges();
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {

                string WorkSheetName = "Sheet1";
                IXLWorksheet WorkSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, WorkSheetName);
                Bitmap Image = null;


                long ImgHeight = 100;
                long ImgWidth = 100;


                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["FilePath"]));

                    if (bitmap != null)
                    {
                        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                        if (stream != null)
                        {
                            stream.Position = 0;

                            XLPicture pic = new XLPicture
                            {
                                NoChangeAspect = true,
                                NoMove = false,
                                NoResize = false,
                                ImageStream = stream,
                                Name = "image",
                                EMUOffsetX = 4,
                                EMUOffsetY = 6,
                                MaxHeight = 100,
                                MaxWidth = 100,
                                PaddingX = 10,
                                PaddingY = 10
                            };

                            XLMarker fMark = new XLMarker
                            {
                                ColumnId = 8,
                                RowId = i +1 
                            };

                            pic.AddMarker(fMark);

                            WorkSheet.AddPicture(pic);
                        }
                    }

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=download.xlsx");

                    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }

            }


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

//Please use this code and let us know your comments.

Comment: Hello Mayil...Thnq..thnq very much...if i tried above code i get error on   XLPicture pic = new XLPicture ...even i added above dlls alos.. what is namespaces your written for above dlls?

Comment: Hi,
Seems Closedxml.dll not having the required functions. Please download the latest version of closed xml and take the “ClosedXml.dll” from there and add in your project.
URL to download the latest ClosedXml.dll: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/ajwhiteway/ClosedXMLImageSupport
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hello.. -Mayil. .thanq. .it's working.. but here it exports only first  image only.

Comment: Loop has to be closed before downloaded the excel. close the for loop before the following line. Response.Clear();

Comment: Hello -Mayil. it's working fine but, here i have 2 issues, one is im unable to change image width and height( i am trying to change in  XLPicture pic = new XLPicture) and another is, in Guideline row data  show three time's. here i am attaching my snap what ever i generated excel file in below.

Comment: and also i am not able to align images to particular row cell.